# how to upload images through mobile services in windows 8 app using c# and also download download image from storage

Tags: azure, windows-8, cloud, azure-blob-storage

I am working on an application in which i want to upload images to azure storage in windows 8 application through one button and from other button I want to retrieve image somewhere in my project but I am not getting any proper working code can any one help me out with that.

For uploading image I am using this code:

```
     private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Objects/variables for the account, client uploading 
        // capability and the blob container 
        CloudStorageAccount account;
        CloudBlobClient blobClient;
        CloudBlobContainer container;


        //You could use local development storage 
        //   account = CloudStorageAccount.DevelopmentStorageAccount; 
        account = new CloudStorageAccount(
            new StorageCredentials(" name",
                " Key "), true);

        // blobClient is used to upload photos 
        blobClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        try
        {
            // The container name in Windows Azure Storage is "mypictures" 
            container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("mypictures");
            await container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

            // Make the photos publicly visible 
            BlobContainerPermissions permissions = new BlobContainerPermissions();
            permissions.PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob;
            await container.SetPermissionsAsync(permissions);

            // Get a reference to the local machine's Pictures folder 
            StorageFolder storageFolder = KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary;

            // Get all files in the pictures folder 
         IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> storageFiles = await storageFolder.GetFilesAsync();


                          CloudBlockBlob blob = null;
            // Loop through pictures 
            foreach (StorageFile StorageFile in storageFiles)
            {
                using (IRandomAccessStream imageStream = await StorageFile.OpenReadAsync())
                {
                    // Name the file in the cloud the same as on local files sytem 
                    blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(StorageFile.Name);
                    // Upload file to Windows Azure Storage 
                    await blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(imageStream);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        } 
    }
```

but when I am clicking on the button to upload image it doesn't work at all means it doesn't open picture library.

Comment: I just tried your code and it worked perfectly fine for me. What error are you getting?

Comment: problem is that when I am clicking on button then it is not opening pictures folder

Comment: I believe this line of code `IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> storageFiles = await storageFolder.GetFilesAsync();` will list all files in the `Pictures` library. You would need a file picker to open the file chooser dialog box. This link should help: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/File-picker-sample-9f294cba.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void image_upload_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CameraCaptureTask camera = new CameraCaptureTask();
    camera.Show();
    camera.Completed += camera_Completed;
}

private void camera_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
{
    txtProgress.Text = string.Empty;

    if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
    {

        BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
        bitmap.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);

        WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(bitmap);

        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            wb.SaveJpeg(stream, wb.PixelWidth, wb.PixelHeight, 0, 85);
            byte[] imageBytes = stream.ToArray();

            AzureStorage storage = new AzureStorage();
            storage.Account = "azure storage";
            storage.BlobEndPoint = "azure end point";
            storage.Key = "you azure key";

            string fileName = "CapturedImage-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + ".jpg";

            bool error = false;
            if (!error)
            {
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => txtProgress.Text += "Uploading image into Cloud...");
                storage.PutBlob("test", fileName, imageBytes, error);
                if (!error)
                {
                    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => txtProgress.Text += "Updating informations...");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error uploading the new Avatar.\nCode: [PUT]\n");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error uploading the new Avatar.\nCode: [DEL]\n");
            }
```